# Can a manager decline a request for a sick day?

Tags: canada, corporate-law, medical

At work can a manger tell an employee that they must come in to work after requesting a sick day? What if the reason is something like they need to go to the dentist to get their annual teeth cleaning? Does it matter if the employee is not entitled to any sick days?

Comment: It wouldn't be a "request" if there wasn't a chance of hearing "no".  If there is an entitlement (as referred to in the last sentence) what does the employee handbook state as to the process or terms to use the entitlement?

Comment: We phrase these as requests, but the manager better have a darn good reason for declining them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell the employee they must come to work? Or else... what? If they don't show up they get a demerit and after 1,000,000 demerits they get a verbal warning? What are the consequences in this hypothetical?

Of course a contract may dictate a different rule but in an at-will-employment state a manager can certainly tell an employee that they must come to work and can fire or discipline them if they don't come to work.

Exceptions that might apply are instances where the employee is physically disabled or otherwise covered by the ADA and also situations where FMLA in implicated.

Regarding ADA the rule is reasonable accommodation including modifying work schedules which may give the employer room to dictate timing of appointments. For example if the employee works 1:00 PM to 9:00 PM but continuously takes off work to go to doctors appointments.